# PHP foreach loop help

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach, modulus

Hoping someone can help me,

I have array of images on my website, it looks similar to this,

```
$usp = array('/images/usp1.jpg',
             '/images/usp2.jpg', 
             '/images/usp3.jpg', 
             '/images/usp4.jpg', 
             '/images/usp5.jpg', 
             '/images/usp6.jpg'
            );
```

I have a page the loops through my products and displays a product image and some details in an `li`. What I am wanting to do it start the loop off with a random selection from the `$usp` array and then show 4 products, then place another random selection from the `$usp` array, then show another 4 products and then show another random selection from the `$usp` array.

In essence I want this effect

```
USP PRODUCT PRODUCT  
PRODUCT PRODUCT USP  
PRODUCT PRODUCT PRODUCT  
PRODUCT USP PRODUCT  
PRODUCT PRODUCT PRODUCT  
USP PRODUCT PRODUCT
```

Currently this is the loop I have.

```
   <?php if(count($product_sets) >= 1) : ?>
                <div class="clear clearfix productWrap" id="homeBestSellers">
                    <!-- <h3 class="label"><?php echo $category_details->categoryTitle; ?> <br> Product Sets</h3> -->

                    <ul class="clear clearfix productBoxes">
                    <?php
                    $number_of_blanks = (3 - (count($product_sets) % 3)); // 0, 1 or 2.
                    if ($number_of_blanks == 3) :
                        $number_of_blanks = 0;
                    endif;
                    $number_of_rows = ceil(count($product_sets) / 3);
                    $currentItem = 1;
                    foreach ($product_sets as $product)
                    {
                        $currentRow = ceil($currentItem / 3);
                        $currentColumn = $currentItem - (($currentRow - 1) * 3);
                        if ($number_of_blanks == 2) :
                            if (($number_of_rows > 1 && $currentRow == ($number_of_rows - 1) && $currentColumn == 2) || ($number_of_rows == 1 && $currentColumn == 1)) :
                                ?>
                                <li><img src="<?php echo site_url('assets/img/blocks/guarantee.png'); ?>" alt="5 Year Guarantee" width="242" height="156"></li>
                                <?php
                                $currentItem++;
                            endif;
                        endif;
                        ?>
                        <li class="<?php if($currentItem % 3 == 0) echo 'endHomeBlock';?>">
                            <?php $this->load->view('blocks/product_small', array('product' => $product)); ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php
                        $currentItem++;

                    }
                    if ($number_of_blanks > 0) :
                        ?>
                        <li><img src="<?php echo site_url('assets/img/blocks/phone-number.png'); ?>" alt="Phone Number" width="242" height="156"></li>
                        <?php
                    endif;
                    ?>
                    </ul><!-- #productSets -->
                </div><!-- #productWrap -->
                <?php endif; ?>
```

How can I modify this so that I have the desired effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert at top of loop (rough concept, may need some modification to fit your code):

```
if ($currentItem % 4 == 0) {        // every fourth item
    $randIndex = array_rand($usp);  // pick random index from $usp
    $randUsp = $usp[$randIndex];
    // code to display $randUsp     // and display it in the table
}
```

**Edit**: As pointed out by @Ben, you may want to remove items from `$usp` as they are used, or keep track of which ones have already been returned, so that the same item isn't returned multiple times if that's a potential problem.

Comment: This could potentially lead to duplicate `$usp` items being returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
shuffle($usp);
foreach ($product_sets as $i => $product) {
    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
        list(, $randUsp) = each($usp);
        echo $randUsp;
    }

    …
}
```

This assumes `$product_sets` is a continuously numerically indexed array. Otherwise use a separate `$i = 0` that you increment each turn.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any $usp items from appearing twice you should do this before your foreach loop:

```
shuffle($usp);
```

And then near the top of your foreach loop:

```
if ($currentItem % 4 == 0) {
    $randusp = array_pop($usp);
    # output $randusp here...
}
```